# Django-dynamic-formsets not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

### Background

I am looking to dynamically add/remove formsets using the django-dynamic-formsets javascript app.

Here is the request.POST data with no additions/deletions (as reference):

```
<QueryDict: {u'set_set-1-test': [u'4'], 
u'set_set-2-id': [u'5'], 
u'set_set-2-test': [u'4'], 
u'set_set-1-id': []
u'ExData_5-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_3-0-numSets': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_3-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-sett': [u'5'], 
u'ExData_4-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_4-0-ex': [u'5'], 
u'ExData_5-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'1'], 
u'ExData_4-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'set_set-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_4-0-sett': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_4-1-ex': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_5-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1'], 
u'set_set-0-id': [u'3'], 
u'add': [u'Add Set'], 
u'ExData_3-1-repScheme': [u'15-15-15-15'], 
u'ExData_3-0-ex': [u'1'], 
u'ExData_5-0-numSets': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-id': [u'5'], 
u'ExData_3-0-sett': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_4-0-numSets': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_3-1-numSets': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_3-1-id': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-repScheme': [u'amap-amap'], 
u'ExData_4-0-id': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-0-DELETE': [u'', 
u'', 
u''], 
u'ExData_4-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_3-0-repScheme': [u'10-8-6'], 
u'ExData_4-1-numSets': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-2-DELETE': [u'', 
u''], 
u'ExData_4-1-repScheme': [u'10-10-10'], 
u'ExData_3-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'set_set-0-workout': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_4-1-id': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_3-1-ex': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-ex': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-1-DELETE': [u'', 
u'', 
u''], 
u'ExData_3-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_4-0-repScheme': [u'15-12-12']}>
```

And Here is the request.POST data when 1 addition is made:

```
    <QueryDict: {u'set_set-1-workout': [u'4'], 
u'set_set-2-id': [u'5'], 
u'set_set-2-workout': [u'4'], 
u'set_set-1-id': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_3-1-sett': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_3-0-id': [u'1'], 
u'ExData_4-1-sett': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_5-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_3-0-numSets': [u'3'], 
u'-NaN-set_set-2-id': [u''], 
u'set_set-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_3-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-sett': [u'5'], 
u'ExData_4-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'-NaN-ExData_5-0-repScheme': [u'2'], 
u'-NaN-ExData_5-0-ex': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_4-0-ex': [u'5'], 
u'ExData_5-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'1'], 
u'ExData_4-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'set_set-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_4-0-sett': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_4-1-ex': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_5-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1'], 
u'set_set-0-id': [u'3'], 
u'add': [u'Add Set'], 
u'ExData_3-1-repScheme': [u'15-15-15-15'], 
u'ExData_3-0-ex': [u'1'], 
u'ExData_5-0-numSets': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-id': [u'5'], 
u'ExData_3-0-sett': [u'3'], 
u'ExData_4-0-numSets': [u'3'], 
u'-NaN-set_set-2-workout': [u''], 
u'set_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_3-1-numSets': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_3-1-id': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-repScheme': [u'amap-amap'], 
u'-NaN-ExData_5-0-sett': [u''], 
u'ExData_4-0-id': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-0-DELETE': [u'', 
u'', 
u''], 
u'ExData_4-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'ExData_3-0-repScheme': [u'10-8-6'], 
u'ExData_4-1-numSets': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-2-DELETE': [u'', 
u''], 
u'ExData_4-1-repScheme': [u'10-10-10'], 
u'ExData_3-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
u'set_set-0-workout': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_4-1-id': [u'4'], 
u'ExData_3-1-ex': [u'2'], 
u'ExData_5-0-ex': [u'3'], 
u'set_set-1-DELETE': [u'', 
u'', 
u''], 
u'-NaN-ExData_5-0-numSets': [u'1'], 
u'ExData_3-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], 
u'-NaN-ExData_5-0-id': [u''], 
u'ExData_4-0-repScheme': [u'15-12-12']}>
```

As you can see, there are 'NaN's littered throughout the second request.POST data, which I would assume means that that the django-dynamic-formsets javascript is looking in the wrong place for the identification numbers (before name)

### Question

1). What is the incompatibility between the format of my request data and what the django-dynamic-formsets javascript is looking for?

2). More importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: I've given solution, how to make dynamic formset a little bit easier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475994/how-do-i-save-all-inline-forms-that-adding-by-javascript/17490853#17490853

Answer (score 1):

you should add/change the prefix in your javascript code. it's selecting the wrong html that's why it's output have NaN (Not a Number) fields.